# Zoom in fullscreen with Adobe Reader

Tags: adobe-reader

Fullscreen mode in Adobe Reader 9 seems to have only one zoom level for the page. Is it possible to zoom in, zoom out, or fit the page width to monitor width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **ctrl + mousewheel** to zoom in and out, even in fullscreen mode.

(Note that this, and Rabarberski's solution, also work in all major browsers.)

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use your mouse, the following keyboard shortcuts work both in normal view and in fullscreen:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd>: full page
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>: zoom to 100%
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>: page width
- for more control you can use
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>plus</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>minus</kbd> to zoom in and out as you want (they do the same as ctrl+mousewheel).

And a last useful shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>
This goes to 'Reading mode', hiding most of the taskbars at the top and the left. It's not the same as fullscreen mode, but is sometimes useful if you want to maximize the reading area but still have your Windows taskbar (and Acrobat's menu) available.

Comment: Has this changed? When I press `CTRL+0` in Adobe Acrobat/Reader DC, the same happens as when I press `CTRL+Plus`, i.e. Acrobat zooms in ‍♂️